# Samsung Galaxy S3 Wi-Fi connection problems

Tags: wi-fi, samsung, connection-issues

When I try to connect to Wi-Fi on my Samsung Galaxy S4, a message comes up, "Checking the quality of your internet connection..." and then "Network disabled because Internet connection is slow". This happens at home and when out and about when other devices connect straight away. This has only been happening in the past 4 to 6 weeks.

How to fix this issue?

Comment: Do you have *switch to mobile data* activated in your wifi settings? try disabling it.

Answer (score -1):

I think it can be disabled in the WiFi menu. Press the hardware "Menu" button, then go to settings.

Comment: Sorry, but as of current writing, this answer lacks enough detail: which specific settings should be disabled?